# Random Spawning in certain locations

Tags: swift, random, constraints, skspritenode

How can you spawn SKSpritenodes randomly inside other SKSpritenodes? Maybe using constraints (in Swift)?

For example, I would like circles to spawn in random places inside different square SKSpriteNodes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, it's much better to use CGRects to contain the object that you are going to spawn.

You can use arc4random_uniform to get a random value for both the X and Y coordinates of the object that you are spawning and then use CGRectContainsPoint to check if the location is inside the CGRect.